# How to enable borders in Grid in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm building a grid in Xamarin.Forms.
And I'd like to add borders like tables.
I thought that I could add the border when defining rows and columns, but failed.
Can anyone help me?
This is my current code.

```
Grid grid = new Grid {
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    RowDefinitions = {
        new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
        new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
        new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
        new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
        new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
        new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
        new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
        new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
        new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
        new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
        new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },

    },
    ColumnDefinitions = {
        new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength (1, GridUnitType.Star) },
        new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength (5, GridUnitType.Star) },
        new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength (1, GridUnitType.Star) },
    }
};
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There's no `Border` property for `GridView`, but:

Just set `grid.BackgroundColor` to your desired border color value, then set `grid.ColumnSpacing` and `grid.RowSpacing` to some value and make sure all controls you add to the grid have own `BackgroundColor` set correctly.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something. This creates borders that are uneven - ie: The top and bottom of the grid would be 1 pixel, but the separators would all be 2 pixels. The lack of proper box-model seems to be a real problem for a fundamental control such as this.

Comment: I agree, this only works with a simple grid. I have a list of grids, with images, variable number of columns, and all the columns need to have the same width, across the whole list. Do not want to use BoxView to try and get cell borders.

Comment: @Kinetic - Use "Padding" on Grid to set the line thickness around the outside. Padding=2, RowSpacing=2, ColumnSpacing=2 would give 2 (device-independent) pixels everywhere.

Answer (score 36):

Here is the full answer (in XAML) without needing to write a custom renderer or Effect.

The code is little verbose but easy to understand and the result is like on the image

[image]

Here is the code to put the borders on your grid (and whats more you´ll have total control over them like you notice there is no blue line on the far left)

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="White">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="1" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
  <!--Your stuff here!-->
  <BoxView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="1" VerticalOptions="End"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
   <!--Your stuff here!-->
  <BoxView Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="1" VerticalOptions="End"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
   <!--Your stuff here!-->
  <BoxView Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="1" VerticalOptions="End"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

  <!--Vertical lines and no "stuff"-->
  <BoxView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="7"  BackgroundColor="Blue" WidthRequest="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
  <BoxView Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="7"  BackgroundColor="Blue" WidthRequest="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
  <BoxView Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="7"  BackgroundColor="Blue" WidthRequest="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
  <BoxView Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="7"  BackgroundColor="Blue" WidthRequest="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Nice. Too bad Xamarin doesn't just provide something to paint rectangles and text, I could probably create my grid with fewer lines of code than this xaml stuff.

Comment: Oh and images. Would save a lot of time and effort.

Comment: Problem here is that you can't have a vertical on the far left because the same column is used to define a horizontal border. Instead, I created one box for each row for each vertical and then drew one horizontal for each row. The other way around didn't work - the vertical wouldn't stretch the full height.

Comment: That's a maintenance nightmare

Answer (score 16):

[image]

```
  <Grid BackgroundColor="White" >
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Pink"  />
        <Grid BackgroundColor="White" Margin="5">

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: I was talking about the spacing borders between rows and columns.

Comment: the best work around is using frame but currently its not working on android 
<Frame OutlineColor="Red" WidthRequest="20"> <StackLayout> <Label Text="sdf"/> </StackLayout> </Frame>

Answer (score 7):

Just noticed my example is similar to Sturla's but a little different so I will leave it up.

The code is not super pretty but I did something similar by adding a 1px `BoxView` between each column and then 1 on top of your `Grid` and one on the bottom of your `Grid`, like so:

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      RowSpacing="0"
      ColumnSpacing="0">

  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <BoxView BackgroundColor="Black"
           HeightRequest="1"
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           Grid.Row="0"/>

  <Grid VerticalOptions="Start"
        ColumnSpacing="0"
        Grid.Row="1">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Text="Button 1"/>

    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Black"
             WidthRequest="1"
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             Grid.Column="1"/>

    <Button Text="Button 1"
            Grid.Column="2"/>
  </Grid>

  <BoxView BackgroundColor="Black"
           HeightRequest="1"
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

*Edit: Since writing this, I have changed the way I do it a bit. Now, like Daniel Luberda's answer, I simply set the `Grid.BackgroundColor` to `Color.Black` and then I can remove all of the `BoxView`s and I am done. I do this because I assume it is much better to have few views on the screen, especially if you are putting something like the above in a `ListView`.

Also, since a lot of my pages will animate the `Button`s when the page load (using `ScaleTo()`) I initially set the `Grid.BackgroundColor` to `Color.Transparent` or `Color.White` and then once the animation is done, I change it to `Color.Black`. Has worked pretty well so far.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like a solution with more equal borders than Daniel Luberda'S anwser, here's what i used :

Make a Grid in which you want element to have borders. Put the spacing between colomns and rows to 0. For each element of the Grid make another Grid with a Boxview in it, and your view on top of that Boxview. Then,put each BoxView to fill and expand. Then adjust the padding of these "under"-Grids as you'd like. Each element of your grid will be separated equaly.

This is pretty heavy though.

Comment: Could you share some C# for that? That would be soooo great.

Comment: NOTE: *"For each element of the Grid make another Grid with a Boxview in it"*  This will be a LOT of "nested" Grids. Such a page may be slow to appear, if there are many rows and columns. For speed, use "hardcoded" (e.g. "20" not "Auto") sizes for rows and columns of the outer Grid.